# Is It possible to in some type of way make a variable in javascript have this ---> var phone number = "(" + Array[1] + Array[2] + Array[3] ")"

Tags: javascript, variables, tostring

this is my code

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers)
{
  const phonelimit = [10]
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
      var j = i + 1
      if (i == 9)
        {
          j -= 10
          
        }
      phonelimit[i] = j
      
      
    }
   var phoneNumber = "(" + phonelimit[0] + phonelimit[1] + phonelimit[2] + ") " + phonelimit[3] + phonelimit[4] + phonelimit[5] + "-" + phonelimit[6] + phonelimit[7] + phonelimit[8] + phonelimit[9])
   return phoneNumber
}
```

my problem is that i am using a site called codehs for my highschool Java + javascript

and it only will allow me to submit it if it outputed using a return not a causal console.log

so some how i need to put all this junk that makes the phone number string into a variable then return the variable

I tried to do multiple toString() methods to create the whole format of the phone number thing with the numbers one variable but they didn't work

[while trying to use console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRxIN.png)

Comment: Your code isn't valid JS. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Are you having an issue with your code? If so, what is it? What do you expect it to do vs what does it actually do?

Comment: You're putting 10 values into the array, but then you only want the first 3. This doesn't make a lot of sense. What is the goal?

Comment: @Pointy scroll right

Comment: @Phil oh god, fine then

Comment: What is `numbers` for? It's never used? FYI you can more easily create a range array using `Array.from({length:10},(_,i)=>(i+1)%10)`

Comment: Ik its junky but i really just now need a fix on how do i return the value as a variable by tansfering the big long console long into a small string

Comment: Your code always returns "(123)456-7890". You could just return that without the additional code, so I suspect you actually want to do something else, correct?

Comment: yes my code returns that but in code hs i need to use return statement

Comment: Can you post the original text of the coding challenge you're solving on CodeHS? This would help us understand what the actual requirements are. I'm guessing that you need to make a function, with a numerical string as its argument, and that the function in question should return a string formatted like phone number - e.g. (xxx) xxx-xxxx.

Answer (score 1):

Following OP's own answer the task seems to have been about formatting a telephone number. OP's answer seems to have fulfilled their requirements, although some parts seem questionable. For example, what is `const phonelimit = [10]` expected to do? Yes, it simply creates an array with a single element of value 10.

The following snippet will do the job in a slightly shorter way:

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbers){
 return numbers.replace(/(...)(...)(.{1,4}).*/,"($1) $2-$3")
}

// testing:
console.log(["0123456789","02468101214","9876541","123"].map(createPhoneNumber));
```

The question did not specify the min or max numbers of digits the phone number is expected to have. The above presented function `createPhoneNumber()` expects at least 7 digits and will ignore any digit after the tenth. This can, of course, be adjusted to requirements by changing the regular expression.

Answer (score -4):

I fixed this by using the numbers variable and instead of j, I used the variable numbers and changed how the variable is returned

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) 
{ const phonelimit = [10]; 
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
      phonelimit[i] = numbers[i]; 
    }  
 numbers = `(${phonelimit[0]}${phonelimit[1]}${phonelimit[2]}) 
 ${phonelimit[3]}${phonelimit[4]}${phonelimit[5]}-${phonelimit[6]}
 ${phonelimit[7]}${phonelimit[8]}${phonelimit[9]}`; 
 return numbers;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `[10]` does not create an array with the length of 10. It creates an array with a single value of 10. Since it's overwritten in the loop it's pointless. You could just use `[]` to create an empty array. The variable parameter `numbers` seems to already contain an array, which you copy in the loop. There is no real point of that. You can just use `numbers` directly. It's also bad form to reuse a variable for a different purpose, in this case create a string in what previously was an array. ...

Comment: ... This can be simplified to ``function createPhoneNumber(numbers) { return `(${numbers[0]}${numbers[1]}${numbers[2]}) ${numbers[3]}${numbers[4]}${numbers[5]}-${numbers[6]} ${numbers[7]}${numbers[8]}${numbers[9]}`; }``